# System.setOut with PipedOutputStream

Tags: java, swing, console, swingworker

I have develop a small console using JTextArea. I read some tutorials and know something. But still I have a problem.  This is my code.

```
public class Console extends JFrame {

    public Console() throws IOException {
        setSize(492, 325);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        setVisible(true);

        final JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
        add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("test");
        add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Test with Button Click.."); // this is not print in textarea.
            }
        });

        final PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
        PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
        System.out.println("Test Before setOut.");
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(pos, true));

        System.out.println("Test After setOut."); // this is printed in my textarea.
        new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(pis);
                while (scan.hasNextLine())
                    area.append(scan.nextLine());
                return null;
            }

        }.execute();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Console();
    }
}
```

This is my output..
[image: Output]

When the button is clicked, System.out.println not work with textarea. I don't know what i'm does wrongly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `SwingWorker.execute()`, it only runs once. So here, it reads the first `println()`, reaches the end of the document, and stops running.

A better solution would be to implement your own `OutputStream` and have its `write()` method append to the text area, using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure this is done on the AWT thread.

Something roughly like this:

```
class TextAreaOut extends OutputStream implements Runnable {
    JTextArea text;
    String buffer = "";

    TextAreaOut(JTextArea text) {
        this.text = text;
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(this));
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        text.append(buffer);
        buffer = "";
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if(buffer.length() == 0) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
        }
        buffer += (char)b;
    }
}
```

Comment: so any other solution..?

Answer (score 2):

I found using piped streams confusing. You can check out [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) for a different approach.